# SPARK : Files read under directory and some files missing columns with header column

Tags: csv, pyspark

I have a 4 files  under directory and one file is missing one column with that column data

But when i load in to the spark DF it is not adding 2nd column and not filling null

```
                    file1.csv
                    name| first|second|
                    female|   raj| tarun|

                    file2.csv
                    name| first|second|
                    female|   raj| tarun|

                    file3.csv
                    name| first|second|
                    female|   raj| tarun|


                    file4.csv
                    name| second|
                    female|  tarun|





                    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
                    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
                    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext



                    un = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').option("delimiter",",").load('/dir/test/')
                    un.show()
                    un.registerTempTable("un1")


                    queryresult1 = sqlContext.sql("select DISTINCT hashedId from un1   ")


                    queryresult1.show()


                    Output is :  why second column is not filling with nul and third column did not shifted

                    +------+------+------+
                    |  name| first|second|
                    +------+------+------+
                    |female|   raj| tarun|
                    |female|   raj| tarun|
                    |female|   raj| tarun|
                    |  name|second|  null|
                    |female| tarun|  null|
```

I have a 4 files  under directory and one file is missing one column with that column data

But when i load in to the spark DF it is not adding 2nd column and not filling null

Comment: what did the output look like? One way around this would be use textFile to read it in as an RDD, then split each line on the comma and then map it to pad out the missing columns with nulls, then convert to DataFrame. If you are happy to do things that roundabout way I can write up an answer for you.

Comment: I have added only sample files , Originally i  have CSV files with me still whatever best you can suggest me

Comment: if the answer below was helpful to you, please consider accepting it, or alternatively, let me know if you have any issues with it and I can amend.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked this fully, but the code below should get you started:

```
columns=['name', 'first', 'second']

df = sc.textFile(path to your folder)
    .map(lambda line: line.split("|")
    .filter(lambda line: line[0]!='name')
    .map(lambda line: line if len(line)==3 else [line[0],None, line[1]])
    .toDF(schema=columns)
```

Explanation: Read in as an RDD and split on pipe delimiter. Filter to get rid of header row in each partition. Then, where a column is missing (i.e. length of rdd element is 2), pad with null. Finally convert to a dataframe.